# inner join results of "with" clause

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have 2 with clauses like this:

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT tfsp.SubmissionID,
                tfsp.Amount,
                tfsp.campaignID,
                cc.Name
         FROM   tbl_FormSubmissions_PaymentsMade tfspm
                INNER JOIN tbl_FormSubmissions_Payment tfsp
                  ON tfspm.SubmissionID = tfsp.SubmissionID
                INNER JOIN tbl_CurrentCampaigns cc
                  ON tfsp.CampaignID = cc.ID
         WHERE  tfspm.isApproved = 'True'
                AND tfspm.PaymentOn >= '2013-05-01 12:00:00.000' AND tfspm.PaymentOn <= '2013-05-07 12:00:00.000')
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount,
       campaignID,
       Name
FROM   T
GROUP  BY campaignID,
          Name;
```

and also:

```
WITH T1
     AS (SELECT tfsp.SubmissionID,
                tfsp.Amount,
                tfsp.campaignID,
                cc.Name
         FROM   tbl_FormSubmissions_PaymentsMade tfspm
                INNER JOIN tbl_FormSubmissions_Payment tfsp
                  ON tfspm.SubmissionID = tfsp.SubmissionID
                INNER JOIN tbl_CurrentCampaigns cc
                  ON tfsp.CampaignID = cc.ID
         WHERE  tfspm.isApproved = 'True'
                AND tfspm.PaymentOn >= '2013-05-08 12:00:00.000' AND tfspm.PaymentOn <= '2013-05-14 12:00:00.000')
SELECT SUM(Amount) AS TotalAmount,
       campaignID,
       Name
FROM   T1
GROUP  BY campaignID,
          Name;
```

Now I want to join the results of the both of the outputs. How can I do it?

Edited: Added the <= cluase also.

Reults from my first T:

```
Amount-----ID----Name
1000----- 2-----Annual Fund
83--------1-----Athletics Fund
300-------3-------Library Fund
```

Results from my T2

```
850-----2-------Annual Fund
370-----4-------Other
```

The output i require:

```
1800-----2------Annual Fund
83-------1------Athletics Fund
300------3-------Library Fund
370------4-----Other
```

Comment: When posting code, please format it for other to read it with ease. What is the difference between the 2 queries? i.e. the first query will include results for all records (that will come from the 2nd query). Other than date clause, I don't see anything different here.

Comment: this really just looks to me as if you are browsing through entries that were done after a certain point in time and filter out the duplicates, you should use a "UNION SELECT"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need a join. You can use

```
SELECT SUM(tfspm.PaymentOn) AS Amount,
       tfsp.campaignID,
       cc.Name
FROM   tbl_FormSubmissions_PaymentsMade tfspm
       INNER JOIN tbl_FormSubmissions_Payment tfsp
         ON tfspm.SubmissionID = tfsp.SubmissionID
       INNER JOIN tbl_CurrentCampaigns cc
         ON tfsp.CampaignID = cc.ID
WHERE  tfspm.isApproved = 'True'
       AND ( tfspm.PaymentOn BETWEEN '2013-05-01 12:00:00.000' 
                                 AND '2013-05-07 12:00:00.000'
              OR tfspm.PaymentOn BETWEEN '2013-05-08 12:00:00.000' 
                                     AND '2013-05-14 12:00:00.000' )
GROUP  BY tfsp.campaignID,
          cc.Name
```

Comment: almost works for me. But not always the case is same. Mostly this is how it will be: T will get the first week data and T1 will get second week. Edited my original post so that you can easily understand. Thanks for the help.

Comment: @ManishPatel - Edited to be in synch with your edit. Is it deliberate you aren't including anything `>2013-05-07 12:00:00 AND < 2013-05-08 12:00:00`?

Comment: Well I see you've edited it again I won't bother trying to keep up with a moving target but now it looks like you just need to do `SUM(PaymentOn)` and adjust the `WHERE` clause to only include the exact two ranges you want.

Comment: I am really sorry. I am trying to make you clearly understand. I edited my post and added the output i am getting and output i need. Tried formatting into a neat table but not happening. Please check

Comment: I deleted my answer since it didn't support your ever changing post at the end. Obviously, Martin has digged deeper into your queries so he will look after you. GL.

Answer (score 1):

If I am right, after a WITH-clause you have to immediatly select the results of that afterwards. So IMHO your best try to achieve joining the both would be to save each of them into a temporary table and then join the contents of those two together.

UPDATE: after re-reading your question I realized that you probably don't want a (SQL-) join but just your 2 results packed together in one, so you could easily achieve that with what I descibed above, just select the contents of both temporary tables and put a UNION inbetween them.

Answer (score 0):

I was thinking it wrongly. Thanks for the help. This is how i achieved what exactly i want:

```
WITH 
T AS (
SELECT tfsp.SubmissionID , Amount1 =
CASE
WHEN tfspm.PaymentOn  >= '2013-01-10 11:34:54.000' AND tfspm.PaymentOn <= '2013-04-10 11:34:54.000' THEN tfsp.Amount
END
, Amount2 = 
CASE
WHEN tfspm.PaymentOn  >= '2013-05-01 11:34:54.000' AND tfspm.PaymentOn <= '2013-05-23 11:34:54.000' THEN tfsp.Amount
END
 , tfsp.campaignID , cc.Name FROM tbl_FormSubmissions_PaymentsMade tfspm 
INNER JOIN tbl_FormSubmissions_Payment tfsp ON tfspm.SubmissionID = tfsp.SubmissionID 
INNER JOIN tbl_CurrentCampaigns cc ON tfsp.CampaignID = cc.ID
WHERE tfspm.isApproved = 'True'   

)
SELECT ISNULL(SUM(Amount1),0) AS TotalAmount1, ISNULL(SUM(Amount2),0) AS TotalAmount2, campaignID , Name FROM T  GROUP BY campaignID, Name;
```